# How to find hidden malware on Android?

Tags: security, malware, youtube

Today, while watching a YouTube video on my Samsung Galaxy S20 FE 5G, the left half of the video portion was covered with a pinkish/orangish screen with the words "MICROWAVE SPY CAMERA 1.XXXX" (where xxxx was 4 digits that I don't remember).   After about 20 seconds, I clicked the next video and the exact same thing occurred.   I then clicked back to the previous video and the video didn't have this "notice".   Then I returned to the new video and it was no longer there either!

I played one more completely different video and it wasn't on it either.

I tried to look in the developer options for how to see active programs running and it listed about 20, but nothing that stood out as suspicious.

I just now put the phone in airplane mode.

How can I  inspect my phone for evidence of this "screen notice"?
Maybe some kind of cache files containing the "screen notice" or whatever?
Is there a way to get a dump of ALL processes running before it's too late and it terminates, or the cache gets deleted?

Comment: Did you watch the YouTube videos on the browser or on the app? This looks like a "screen overlay", and apps need permission called "display over other apps" to behave like this, so you may check which apps have this permission enabled by going into Settings - Apps - Special app access - Display over other apps (steps may be different depending on the device model).

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I was watching it thru the App. Side note may not be related...but I was doing something earlier (not sure how much earlier) but something gave an option to save to the Sim card, and I didnt mean to do that but I selected that option.   I remember thinking that I never saw that option before.

Comment: Yeah, I dont think this was an Intentional overlay.   Seems like it was just a fluke moment where it revealed itself on 2 separate videos accidentally.   I have gotten some strange phone calls and a few odd Telegram messages in the last 2 months .  I just read about the Pegasus virus/trojan.   You know of this ?   Think that may be related to the "Screen overlay"

Comment: Ok, so in developer options the setting for allowing Overlay screens was not enabled.  I did find a System Tracing option in there.  So I turned it on to run for 8 hours 5GB max file set.  Now how to I inspect that file.  The option for "View trace files" I pressed but the "Open with" options shown are only 4 choices: ZArchiver, My Cloud, Report and Run, and Talking Spanish.  So yeah, not a good bunch of choices to open this file.   Any ideas???